# 7-segment resistors

Tags: resistors, 7segmentdisplay

I am building display using [this 7-segment module](https://www.west-l.com/uploads/tdpdf/tmlsd230bag-101.pdf) with following setup.

[image]

I have problem with understanding 7-segment datasheet.
According to the table typical forward voltage per segment is 8 V at 20 mA. This is large display with 4 leds in series.

[image]

But voltage vs. current graph shows different values: 8.8 V at 20 mA and dropping quickly.

[image]

Is it a mistake or I just don't understand it?

I am trying to get precise values because I would like to use the display outdoors. So I am trying to get such resistor values that the led luminous intensity is high but still at the level that doesn't negatively affect device lifetime. 
I made calculations for 15 mA and 9.5 V supply (DC adapter is 9 V but I add 0.5 V buffer). Looking at the graph I get 8.5 V forward voltage at 15 mA current which means I need ~67 ohm resistor.
On the other hand if the graph values are wrong and it is 8 V or less at 15 mA the resistance is ~100 V or more, almost 2 times bigger.

I know only theory and have no experience, need help to get resistor values for good balance between high brightness and led durability.

Comment: Brightness.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Th Datasheet has both typical and maximum value. You have to accommodate design with upto forward voltage drop of 10 V.   You are not wrong neither the datasheet.

The graph has empirical data based on large number of testing (a guess).

If you want to make sure the brightness is the same, instead of resistor try using a simple constant current driver circuit.

---

Please get a DC adapter of 12 V or higher. Thereby you can be sure that th LEDs are always forward biased and also there so room for the resistor and forward Voltage tolerance.

Comment: I would prefer to stay with 9 V because other circuits in the project depend on it. I have working prototype. I am experimenting with different resistor values brightness but can't measure effective led current anyway.

Comment: The rolling prototype is okay. It is not failproof though. The datasheet means that, some LEDs will have higher forward voltage, greater than the 9V. Datasheet is final. You cal also look for LED current driver with boost options

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain why the table has 8V typical and the graph has 8.8V typical. But, in any case, a 9.5V power supply is not enough if you want consistent brightness. Either use a constant current source (which would require a major redesign), or use a higher voltage. I would use 15V for the LEDs. You can use a lower voltage for the logic.

The spec already says the max is 10V. The minimum voltage drop might be 7V. You need to compromise on the minimum and maximum possible current. 500 ohms is a good compromise.

(15V - 7V)/500 = 16 mA

(15V - 10V)/500 = 10 mA

Also consider how many of these you are building. If it is a small quantity, you can pick the optimum resistor for each.

Comment: With my prototype I am getting consistent brightness with resistors in range 50–200 ohm with 9 V adapter. It probably means that voltage drop is much lower in practice. But you may be right that I should think about higher voltage.

Answer (score 0):

From the data sheet:

> If the brightness of lighting source can meet the requirement, we recommend using the driving current less than the rated current, in order to improve the product’s reliability.

So rated is 8 V at 20 mA, but they recommend driving the LED with less current if the brightness meets the designs needs to extend the life of the LED module.

Lowest being around 6mA @ 8V.  Which would be the lowest level of brightness.